# cargo test-sbf failed with ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections

Tags: build-sbf

Sometimes when we test on-chain program with cargo test-sbf, error would read like this:

`ELF error: Multiple or no text sections, consider removing llc option: -function-sections`

and then we re-compile the program with cargo build-sbf --dump, in corresponding dump.txt, it said:
`There are 8 section headers, starting at offset 0xbc`, WITHOUT any .text section at all.

Env: Mac M1 and Ubuntu x86_64 (same error on both), solana-1.14.17, ./cargo 1.60.0 toolchain, sbf-tools: v1.29

Anyone knows what would be the potential reason which causes .text section missing in ELF? Thanks.

Comment: I found the alternative way worked if I instead still use old/legacy cargo build-bpf or cargo test-bpf. It's quite confusing.